# TeamCity doesn't delete files from 'temp' directory

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I'm using TeamCity 7.5. There is a temp directory under c:\TeamCity with some temp files that TeamCity generates.
The files are really small (450 kb) however after several months the directory becomes huge (30+ GB)!

Is there a way to make TeamCity delete the temporary files by itself?

Comment: All the clean up rules are set. It's not the history or the artifacts that are not deleted - those are the temp files in the temp directory of the TeamCity main directory

Comment: What is the temp directory? Are you talking about `<TeamCity Home>/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp`? TeamCity cleans that up before every run (though of course it may fail to do so if some file handles are open etc.). If it's some other directory, you shouldn't be putting your files there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add "Build files cleaner (Swabra)" build feature. It cleans up agent's working directory if there is not enough disk space. It also cleans up other workspaces on the agent if necessary.

[image]